# Saving GIF with PIL in Python becomes flickery black/white

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library, gif

I am trying to create a small section above a GIF that a user inputs along with some text they can add to mimic that popular GIF meme style. Upon output, the colors of the gif are entirely completely black or completely white with lots of artifacting.

I open the input GIF and create a new image using PIL with the same dimensions, plus a little extra height.

```
        giftemplate = Image.open("input.gif")
# create empty white frame with extra height for text
        result_template = Image.new(giftemplate.mode, size=(base_width, new_height), color=(255, 255, 255))
```

Then I add some text to the extra height and loop over every frame in the gif, pasting the current frame to the new image, then append that frame in a list.

```
# paste each frame of gif under extra height
        frames = []
        for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(giftemplate):
            result_template.paste(frame, (0, padding_size))
            b = BytesIO()
            result_template.save(b, format="GIF")
            result_frame = Image.open(b)
            frames.append(result_frame)
        frames[0].save('meme_out.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], loop=0)
```

Gif used as input -
[Input.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKJ3X.gif)

The generated gif outputted by PIL - [meme_out.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jhUO.gif)

Notice the total lack of color, and (while not so apparent on this example) slowed speed. You can still see a small outline of the cat dancing.

The output gif looks totally fine if I *dont* paste each frame of the gif onto created image with text

EDIT: Reproducible example provided:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageSequence
from io import BytesIO

caption = "sample"
giftemplate = Image.open("input.gif")
font = ImageFont.truetype("Futura Condensed Extra Bold Regular.ttf", 10)
# text margin size scales with image height
text_margin = int((giftemplate.height / 100))

# text width and height
tw, th = font.getsize(caption)
# top left text box coordinate with respect to image pixels. Top left of image is 0,0
cx, cy = int(giftemplate.width / 2), text_margin

padding_size = th
base_width, base_height = giftemplate.size
new_height = base_height + padding_size

# create empty white frame with extra height for text
result_template = Image.new(giftemplate.mode, size=(base_width, new_height), color=(255, 255, 255))

# draw text lines in the extra height
tw, th = font.getsize(caption)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(result_template)
draw.text((cx - tw / 2, cy), caption, (0, 0, 0), font=font)

# paste each frame of gif under extra height
frames = []
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(giftemplate):
    result_template.paste(frame, (0, padding_size))
    b = BytesIO()
    result_template.save(b, format="GIF")
    result_frame = Image.open(b)
    frames.append(result_frame)

frames[0].save('meme_out.gif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], loop=0)
```

Comment: You would get more useful feedback if you were providing a [mre]. It is hard to try to reproduce the problem on our side, filling the gap described in commnts.

Comment: @chrslg My bad, I have created some example code that produces the same effect.